# I'm trying to format only time, removing date and year from DateTime in my code

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
DateTime vSunrise= mapWeatherMap['sunrise'];
DateTime vSunset= mapWeatherMap['sunset'];
```

```
Text(
  '$vSunrise',
  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
  style: TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
    fontSize: 14.sp,
    letterSpacing: 0.2,
    color: AppTheme.grey,
  ),
),
```

I'm trying to do a format like this, but I'm getting with year month

Comment: What is mapWeatherMap? Please elaborate your requirements.

Comment: it is a method I'm fetching five days of weather data and displaying

Comment: Please add that method code here. Also add what is your exact requirement

Comment: mWeatherMap['weather_code']=weather.weatherConditionCode;
             mWeatherMap['temprature_c']=weather.temperature?.celsius;
             mWeatherMap['weather_desc']=weather.weatherDescription;
             mWeatherMap['wind_speed']=weather.windSpeed;
             mWeatherMap['wind_degree']=weather.windDegree;
             lTotdayAndFiveDayWeather.add(mWeatherMap);

Answer (score 1):

You can make an `extension` method (or in this case a getter) on `DateTime` which will do that.
Something like this:

```
extension DateTimeExtension on DateTime {
  String get time {
    final hour = this.hour.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    final minute = this.minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    return "$hour:$minute";
  }
}
```

Now you can use it on the `DateTime` object like:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.now();
print(date.time); // e.g. prints 14:04
```

Comment: The prefix 'date' can't be used here because it's shadowed by a local declaration.   its coming like this

Comment: What??? `date` is a `DateTime` object on which the `time` getter is used. What is the problem there?

Comment: DateTime  vSunrise= mapWeatherMap['sunrise'];
    DateTime vSunset= mapWeatherMap['sunset'];

    DateTime nowDateTime = DateTime.now();
    String sunRiseTime = DateFormat.Hms().format(vSunrise);
    print(sunRiseTime);

Comment: i tried this way and tried to print vSunrise................i got error saying       
   
the getter 'hour' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: hour

Comment: If you try to call `time` getter on a `null` it will give you that error because it expects `DateTime` and not `null`, so you have a problem with `null` exception now, and it obviously doesn't map `mapWeatherMap['sunrise']` to `DateTime` correctly.